# jQuery and the scope of this

Tags: jquery, scope, this

I'm missing something with the scope of this function, I have a cms that  automatically adds classes to images but not but doesn't change their alignment so text does not wrap on around them properly. I cannot simply use $("img").attr("align","left"); because that would change every image on the page, that said using the context '"img", this' is not working like I thought it would and does absolutely nothing.

```
function align_image(){
    console.log("func called");
    if($("img").length){
        if($("img").hasClass("alignleft")){
            $("img", this).attr("align","left");
            console.log("aligned left!")
    }

       if($("img").hasClass("alignright")){
           $("img", this).attr("align","right");
           console.log("aligned right!");
       }
   }
}
align_image();
```

Does anyone out there know how I could change each img to align with its associated class? Bonus points for why it works.

Edit: codepen demo

Comment: the issue is not changing the image alignment, it works fine without "this" the problem is, using "this" the way I currently am does not select anything and if I don't use "this", it selects every image tag on the page and realigns it. So if I have 50 img tags, they will all be aligned whichever way the last one is found is.

Comment: you can use the class identifier to add the attr like $('img.alignleft').attr('align','left'); and similar for alignright class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can iterate through each of the images, and the iterator function refers to the img DOM element with the "this" reference. Something like this:

```js
function align_image(){
    console.log("func called");
    if ($(this).hasClass('alignleft')) {
        $(this).attr("align","left");
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('alignright')) {
        $(this).attr("align","right");
    }
}

$('img').each(align_image);
```

As suggested in the comments (and in other answers), you can also use specific jQuery selectors to accomplish the same:

```js
$('img.alignleft').attr("align","left");
$('img.alignright').attr("align","right");
```

Finally, according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp), the img align attribute is deprecated, and CSS properties should be used instead. Something like this should work:

```css
img.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

img.alignright {
  float: right;
}
```

I hope this captures all the angles.

Comment: This will iterate through all images, and check each one for the classes. If you wanted a bit of a shortcut, you could just do this:
$('img.alignleft').attr("align", "left") and $('img.alignright').attr("align", "right"). This would set the align attributes on all img tags with the alignX classes. Of course, this could all be done with css stylesheets too, right?

Comment: That's great! I'm glad it works! Side note: I would actually recommend using the selectors as suggested in my comment. The method listed in the answer is just a closer match to your original logic. the selectors provide for a much more concise method of manipulating several DOM elements with a single function call, which I believe is one of the greatest strengths of jQuery. Good luck!

Comment: sorry, when you say it could be done with just css, I'm aware of text-align (which doesn't work), but are you saying there is something else that changes the align property on images? I'd much rather do something with css than js.

Comment: I just found here (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp) that the img "align" attribute is deprecated (although still supported in major browsers). It recommends that for vertical alignment, you use the "vertical-align" css property. For horizontal alignment, it recommends using the "float" css property (float: left or float: right).

Comment: I have updated the answer with all of the different solutions that seem like they would address the issue. I hope they are all clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. I think its helpfull for you

```
function align_image(){
    console.log("func called");
   if ($('img').hasClass('alignleft')) {
    $(this).attr("align","left");
    }

   if ($('img').hasClass('alignright')) {
    $(this).attr("align","right");
    }
}
align_image();
```

Comment: that was the first thing I tried, I thought that would select whichever image it was currently listening for and change it. It doesn't seem to know what "this" is in that case.

Comment: could you provide demo  then i can help you.

Comment: I'll get one up asap

Answer (score 0):

You better use filter method to find your element and add an attr like this:

```
$("img").filter('.align-right').attr("align","right") ;                           
$("img").filter('.align-left').attr("align","left") ;
```

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ksvL7dg/)